# How to calculated on created fields? Why the calculation is wrong?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am working on the workforce analysis project. And I did some case when conditional calculations in Google Data Studio. However, when I successfully conducted the creation of the new field, I couldn't do the calculation again based on the fields I created.

Based on my raw data, I generated the start_headcount, new_hires, terminated, end_headcount by applying the Case When conditional calculations. However, I failed in the next step to calculate the Turnover rate and Retention rate.

The formula for Turnover rate is 
    terms/((start_headcount+end_headcount)/2)
for retention is 
    end_headcount/start_headcount
However, the result is wrong. Part of my table is as below:

```
Supervisor  sheadcount  newhire  terms  eheadcount  turnover  Retention
    A          1            3      1         3      200%          0%
    B          6            2      2         6      200%         500%
    C          6            1      3         4      600%         300%
```

So the result is wrong. The turnover rate for A should be   1/((1+3)/2)=50%; For B should be 2/((6+6)/2)=33.33%.

I don't know why it is going wrong. Can anyone help?

For example, I wrote below for start_headcount for each employee

```
CASE
WHEN Last Hire Date<'2018-01-01' AND Termination Date>= '2018-01-01'
OR Last Hire Date<'2018-01-01' AND Termination Date IS NULL
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

which means if an employee meets the above standard, will get 1. And then they all grouped under a supervisor. I think it might be the problem why the turnover rate in sum is wrong since it is not calculated on the grouped date but on each record and then summed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are trying to do both steps within the same query and thus newly created fields like start_headcount, etc. not visible yet within the same select statement - instead you need to put first calculation as a subquery as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, terms/((start_headcount+end_headcount)/2) AS turnover  
FROM (
  <query for your first step>
)
```

Comment: Do you know how to apply it in Data Studio?

Comment: you might need to use custom query source for this or just create view in and use it